# Windows Phone Emulator save state

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

I lost all the data I saved into the emulator(contacts, accounts) after closing it.

I need to save the state of emulator before closing it.

I am using [this post](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2013/01/saving-windows-phone-8-emulator-state.html) , but state is not getting saved and setting the state manually takes a lot time.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. The emulator's tools provides `Checkpoints` in order to save/restore state.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words You cant.Every start of an emulator is a clean start. You can only maintain the information you stored in it till you do not close it. Once you close the emulator, all the information like contacts or the apps installed in it get removed automatically.

for an app if you terminate and restart your it while the emulator itself keeps running, all data that your app properly saved is retained.